# Loading data on refresh

Tags: jquery, load

Im using to jQuery to save data then load it into an alert of page refresh

so far I have:

```
$(function() {
    $("#input1").keyup(function() {
        inputvar = $('#input1').val();
        $("#input1").data("key1", inputvar)
    });
});     

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("#input1").data("key1"))
});
```

However this isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: $(function() {
        $("#input1").keyup(function() {
            inputvar = $('#input1').val();
            $("#input1").data("key1", inputvar);
 alert($("#input1").data("key1"));
        });
    });

Comment: You're "saving" in a page you're refreshing. You'd better use localStorage.

Comment: Define "not working."  What are you expecting this code to do?  Currently on page load you `alert` the initial contents of `$("#input1").data("key1")` and you bind a handler to `#input1` to change those contents on `keyup`.  What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 3):

`data()` isn't persisted over a refresh. Try [`localStorage`/`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

In case you're using an old browser, like IE7, which doesn't support this, you can always use [`$.cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You're "saving" in a page you're refreshing (and thus replacing). You'd better use [`localStorage`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage) if you want something persistent :

```
$(function() {
    $("#input1").keyup(function() {
        inputvar = $('#input1').val();
        localStorage['input1'] = inputvar
    });
    alert(localStorage['input1']);
});
```

Comment: when page referesh and not keyup fire the what will come in   alert(localStorage['input1']);  you can always use $.cookie

Comment: +1 for reconstructing OP's code using localStorage. There is no reason to downvote this @Rituraj

Comment: @Riturajratan `$(document).ready(function(){` does the same than `$(function() {`.

Comment: no no @dystroy i am taking about localStorage can you explane me what is this